# VBA-Word bug: Undo list get error if use UndoRecord to record "Replace All" while there is a "Apply Quick Style" in the undo list. How to avoid?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

On Word window, do something like typing, format font, paragraph... to ensure the undo list is not empty, and then change style of some text by clicking any Style on Ribbon. An entry named "Apply Quick Style" appear in the undo list. Then run macro like:

```
Sub SampleMacro()
Dim myUndoRecord As UndoRecord

Set myUndoRecord = Application.UndoRecord
myUndoRecord.StartCustomRecord ("VBA - Format Text")
'I do a lot of step here, but for this example, just simple like below
Selection.Characters(1).Bold = True     'just for example
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Find Text"
    .Replacement.Text = "Replace Text"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
'Word undo list get error after below step
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
'no crash, no error message, but the entry "Apply Quick Style" 
'become to "Replace All", and Word can't go back before that entry
myUndoRecord.EndCustomRecord
End Sub
```

After this line of code:

```
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

The entry named "Apply Quick Style" in the undo list will become to "Replace All" and I can't undo (by press Ctrl-Z, or click arrow button on Quick Access Toolbar) to go back any step before that entry "Replace All". It's allway appear in undo list and Word will not go back anymore. 
How to avoid this bug?
I'm using Word 2016 pro 64 bit

Additional information: using copy paste by press Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V (from other document to current document) instead of "Apply Quick Style" also get error, the entry "Paste" in undo list also rename to "Replace all". The different is still able to go back before that entry. Maybe there is another way will get error if use UndoRecord to record "Replace all".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 10/01**

*A working work around*

The problem is specific to `wdReplaceAll`.  If that specific wdConstant is omitted or replaced then "Apply Quick Style" will not be renamed and the undo stack remains accessible.

Lucky for us, `Find.Execute` returns a Boolean value (True for success).  That means, we can loop with `wdFindOne` to replace all matches and use `.Execute = False` as the exit condition.

Add the word `Do` above your `With` block and replace the line with `.Execute`.

```
Do
    With Selection.Find
         [....]
    End With
Loop While Selection.Find.Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceOne)
```

**A word of caution:** some circumstances will create an infinite loop (*such as replacing "A" with "A"*).  As such, you should consider using a second exit condition or replacing `wdFindContinue` with `wdFindAsk` or `wdFindStop`.

---

**Update 9/30**

*(Edit 10/01) Oops!! The Apply Quick Style entry was not renamed (good) but I wrongly  assumed the undo stack could be reached when the same limitation exists (bad).  Also, testing today, I learned* **there is a third condition: `.Execute` must not find any matches** *(worse).  Suffice it to say, this is an exemplary demonstration of how not to test a solution, I hope everyone learned thier lesson!*

When I create a new document and follow your steps, I can consistently reproduce the issue you describe.  Thank you for making that easy!

As much as I am able to replicate the problem, I am also able prevent it by meeting two conditions.

- Ensure `Replace All` is listed in the `Undo Stack` above `Apply Quick Style`.
- `Replace All` is applied to the entire document (the problem persists if `Replace All` is applied to a `Selection` within the document)

This method worked regardless if it was done manually with 'Ctrl + H' or if it was part of a macro.  Replacing a character with the same character was sufficient.

---

*A screenshot showing the execution point after the problematic line:*

[image: Can be avoided]

---

The `Undo Stack` contains an intentionally placed `Replace All` to preserve `Apply Quick Style`.
This article is for Excel but it's relevant for Word.

https://excel.tips.net/T002060_Preserving_the_Undo_List.html

In short, you're on your own.

You have two options: revert to a previously saved version; or, write a macro that mimics Undo and ensure this macro is running before you start the one that messes with the Undo list

Comment: Thank for answer, however, I don't know the same Application.OnUndo in VBA-Word, may Word does not have same thing? Writing a macro that mimics Undo is complex for a lot of step with loop and conditions (in my main code, not this sample code) and after bug occurs, it's still not able to go back before "Replace All" entry. Revert to a previously saved version may good ideal, but not in my case now.

Comment: @Mr.Tien I understand you and empathize with you. My distributed applications use saved files to work around the issue.  I prompt the user to save before continuing on the small jobs.  On big jobs I will save a copy in a temp folder and delete the file after the next save event.  I prompt the user to restore if the application loads and the temp folder isn't empty.  I've gotten positive feedback from users who closed the file intending to revert to thier previous save without knowing I saved a copy. 
They we're thrilled to recover a more recent version.

Comment: I'll the language is the same.  I'll try recreating the problem later today and update the my answered with results.

Comment: I am trying to do something around undo list to avoid this bug. Hope to see your result.

Comment: thank for answer, I try to do as I understand your guide, but result no change. May you write your steps in more detail? My steps: New > type "Find Text" > change to style Heading 1 > press Ctrl+H > type "Text" in both Find what and Replace with > click Replace all ( an entry named "Replace all" appear above the entry "Apply Quick Style" )> Run macro in my question, but bug still occurs, the entrry "Apply Quick Style" become to "Replace all" and can't go back to before that entry.

Comment: @Mr.Tien  You were doing it right but my testing was embarrassingly inadequate.  Explanation will be posted above.  Also, the new workaround should work!

Comment: Using wdReplaceOne will avoid bug. I still haven't found a better way to do it. Your way is good for small job. However, this is not good ideal for my task, it's take much time to loop through long document (about 700 pages each document). As my testing, a cup of coffee is need for waiting it execute one time. Maybe I have to find another solution.

Comment: By using Range.Find.Execute instead of Selection.Find.Excecute, and disable Application.ScreenUpdating, macro run faster much. I think user can wait. I try to make the app convenient and run as fast as possible. That is why I want to find a more optimal solution. But currently I can't find a better way, I'll improve the macro next time. Thanks for your help very much. :)